# how to set up path in .cshrc?

Tags: path

I am installing one software in linux. How to setup path in `.cshrc`.

The directory of my software is `/home/software`. Now I want to set up its path in `.cshrc` file. Using `vi .cshrc` I extended the `PATH` with `export PATH="$PATH:/home/software"` but after saved it, when I typed `source .cshrc` it gave `Bad : modifier in $ (/). Path has not set yet`.

Can any one rectify my problem.

Comment: What is the name of the shell are you using? (`csh`? `bash`?)

Comment: @don_crissti I know. I'd like to hear confirmation from the OP though